# Typesafe queries for TopLink

Tags: toplink

Is there any other way to do typesafe queries with TopLink than through the JPA 2.0 Criteria API?

From a sales meeting I got the impression that this is possible through a proprietary part in TopLink, but I couldn't find any related documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JPA 2.0 is the only way.

TopLink does also provide Expression objects, but they are not typed.
If you just want dynamic queries, you can use Expressions instead of Criteria.

Comment: that's what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use alternative library like [query dsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) or [object query](http://www.objectquery.org/%20Object%20Query)